# ¿Como saber si hay numeros seguidos verticalmente y horizontalmente en una matriz en c++ recursivo?

Tags: c++

Tengo la siguiente matriz:

```
1 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1
0 1 1 0 1 1
```

Los `1`'s representan las "islas" (números seguidos verticalmente y horizontalmente), que se refiere a que se encuentran juntos. ¿Cómo puedo saber los que números están juntos y cuantas islas hay, de forma recursiva?

En este caso son 5 islas por lo siguiente:

---

```
1 - - - - -      - - - 1 - -      - - - - - -      - - - - - -      - - - - - -
- - - - - -      - - - - - -      - 1 - - - -      - - - - - -      - - - - - -
- - - - - -      - - - - - -      - 1 1 - - -      - - - - - -      - - - - - -
- - - - - -      - - - - - -      - - - - - -      - - - 1 1 1      - - - - - -
- - - - - -      - - - - - -      - - - - - -      - - - - 1 1      - 1 1 - - -
```

---

Tengo el siguiente código, pero sin recursividad (hace lo que se necesita pero no es recursivo) o se puede hacer recursivo el codigo?:

```
double conjuntoIslas(int a[][6]){
 int contCol, contFil, pivofil, pivocol, auxFil, auxCol;
 double sum = 0, island = 0;
 bool bol = false;
 contCol = 5;
 contFil = 4;
 while(contCol >= 0 && contFil >= 0){   
  if(a[contFil][contCol] == 1){
   pivofil = contFil;
        pivocol = contCol;
        auxFil = contFil;
        auxCol = contCol;

        cout<<endl<<endl<<"CUADRO EN: "<<contFil<<", "<<contCol<<endl;

        while(pivofil > 0){
            if(a[pivofil-1][pivocol] == 1){
                cout<<endl<<"\t"<<"Cuadro ARRIBA de: "<<pivofil<<", "<<pivocol;
                sum += 1;
                a[pivofil][pivocol] = 0;
                a[pivofil-1][pivocol] = 0;
                pivocol = auxCol;
                while(pivocol > 0){
                    if(a[pivofil-1][pivocol-1] == 1){
                        sum += 1;
                        cout<<endl<<"\t"<<"Cuadro IZQUIERDA de: "<<pivofil-1<<", "<<pivocol;
                        a[pivofil-1][pivocol-1] = 0;
                        pivocol--;
                    }
                    else{
                        pivocol = 0;
                    }
                }
                a[pivofil-1][pivocol] = 0;

                pivocol = auxCol;

                pivofil--;
            }
            else{
                pivofil = 0;
            }
        }
        pivofil = auxFil;
        while(pivocol > 0){
            if(a[pivofil][pivocol-1] == 1){
                cout<<endl<<"\t"<<"Cuadro a la IZQUIERDA de: "<<pivofil<<", "<<pivocol;
                sum += 1;
                a[pivofil][pivocol] = 0;
                a[pivofil][pivocol-1] = 0;
                pivofil = auxFil;
                while(pivofil > 0){
                    if(a[pivofil-1][pivocol-1] == 1){
                        cout<<endl<<"\t"<<"Cuadro ARRIBA de: "<<pivofil<<", "<<pivocol-1;
                        sum += 1;
                        a[pivofil-1][pivocol-1] = 0;
                        pivofil--;
                    }
                    else{
                        pivofil = 0;
                    }
                }
                pivofil = auxFil;
                a[pivofil][pivocol-1] = 0;
                pivocol--;
            }
            else{
                pivocol = 0;
            }
        }
        island += sum/sum;
        a[contFil][contCol] = 0;

    }
    if(contCol == 0){
        contFil--;
        contCol = 5;
    }
    else{
        contCol--;
    }
}
return island;
}
```

Comment: Podrías ser mas claro en tu problema y decir cual es el resultado esperado.

Comment: Buenas noches, ya modifiqué la pregunta. A ver si se entiende un poco mas.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad

Answer (score 3):

Parece un caso adecuado para usar el [Relleno por Difusión](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_relleno_por_difusi%C3%B3n) (Floodfill en Inglés). El pseudocódigo de ese algoritmo podría ser:

1. Si la celda no está visitada.

   1. Marca la celda como visitada.
   2. Si la celda está ocupada.

      - Guarda la coordenada.
      - Visita la celda superior, inferior, izquierda y derecha.

Como puedes ver, el algoritmo es recursivo si se cumple el punto 2. La manera en que lo he implementado yo es en primer lugar creando un objeto de coordenadas y unos alias para facilitar la tarea:

```
struct coordenada { int x{}, y{}; };
using coordenadas = std::vector<coordenada>;
using islas = std::vector<coordenadas>;
```

Después creamos una función (plantilla) que reciba una formación<sup>1</sup> bidimensional genérica sobre la que buscar islas:

```
template <int H, int W>
islas busca_islas(int (&matriz)[H][W])
{
    bool visitado[W][H]{};
    islas resultado{};

    for (int h = 0; h < W; ++h)
    {
        for (int v = 0; v < H; ++v)
        {
            coordenadas isla{};
            busca_islas({v, h}, isla, matriz, visitado);
            if (!isla.empty())
            {
                resultado.push_back(isla);
            }
        }
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Las coordenadas `v` (vertical) y `h` (horizontal) están dadas la vuelta (las `y` antes que las `x`) porque `int[6][6]` significa *seis filas de seis columnas* no *seis columnas de seis filas*. Esta función que sólo recibe una formación de HxW (Height x Width) elementos llama a una sobrecarga que es la que hace la recursión:

```
template <int H, int W>
void busca_islas(const coordenada &c, coordenadas &resultado, int (&matriz)[H][W], bool (&visitado)[H][W])
{
    if (!visitado[c.y][c.x])
    {
        visitado[c.y][c.x] = true;

        if (matriz[c.y][c.x] == 1)
        {
            resultado.push_back(c);
            busca_islas({std::max(c.x - 1, 0), c.y}, resultado, matriz, visitado);
            busca_islas({std::min(c.x + 1, W - 1), c.y}, resultado, matriz, visitado);
            busca_islas({c.x, std::max(c.y - 1, 0)}, resultado, matriz, visitado);
            busca_islas({c.x, std::min(c.y + 1, H - 1)}, resultado, matriz, visitado);
        }
    }
}
```

Las llamadas a `std::min` y `std::max` son para no salirse de los rangos de la formación<sup>1</sup>.

Aplicando ese código sobre tus datos me salen las siguientes islas:

> ```
> { {0, 0} }
> { {3, 0} }
> { {1, 1} {1, 2} {2, 2} }
> { {3, 3} {4, 3} {5, 3} {5, 4} {4, 4} }
> { {1, 4} {2, 4} }
> ```

Que son las que buscabas. Puedes ver el código funcionando <kbd>[Aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sVtmV2G8F4G71F1P)</kbd>.

---

1. También conocida como arreglo (o en inglés: array).